# Simple Tomcat/ Servlets - Getting HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I followed this page's tutorial.http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html and downloaded the test-app zip file. That file is working perfectly. However when I try to create even a simple helloworld Servlet it gives the 404 error. I have seen related questions on the forum too but none of them seem to address the problem. I am using tomcat7 and java6 ee.
I am able to add links to and access static web pages plain HTML pages but get 404 when I try to access servlets. 
This is my servlet code.

```
@WebServlet(name="LoginServlet1",urlPatterns={"/LoginServlet1"})

public class LoginServlet1 extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {


    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println
      ("<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
       "<html>\n" +
       "<head><title>A Test Servlet</title></head>\n" +
       "<body bgcolor=\"#fdf5e6\">\n" +
       "<h1>Test</h1>\n" +
       "<p>Simple servlet for testing.</p>\n" +
       "</body></html>");
  }


}
```

this is my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test Web App for Tomcat 7 or Other Servlet 3.0 Container</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<table class="title">
  <tr><th>Test Web App for Tomcat 7</th></tr>
</table>
<p/>
<fieldset>
<ul>
  <li><a href="LoginServlet1">hello</a> The HelloWorld servlet that
      generates plain text.</li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
<p/>
</body></html>
```

This was the console log during startup.

```
Jun 08, 2014 11:00:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
Jun 08, 2014 11:00:55 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:test-app' did not find a matching property.
Jun 08, 2014 11:00:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 08, 2014 11:00:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 08, 2014 11:00:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 989 ms
Jun 08, 2014 11:00:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 08, 2014 11:00:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Jun 08, 2014 11:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/karan/tomcat eclipse/webapps/SensorWebApplication4
Jun 08, 2014 11:00:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/karan/tomcat eclipse/webapps/examples
Jun 08, 2014 11:00:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 08, 2014 11:00:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 08, 2014 11:00:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@6c814dbd')
Jun 08, 2014 11:00:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/karan/tomcat eclipse/webapps/SensorWebApplication1
Jun 08, 2014 11:01:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/karan/tomcat eclipse/webapps/SensorWebApplication9
Jun 08, 2014 11:01:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/karan/tomcat eclipse/webapps/ROOT
Jun 08, 2014 11:01:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/karan/tomcat eclipse/webapps/host-manager
Jun 08, 2014 11:01:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/karan/tomcat eclipse/webapps/manager
Jun 08, 2014 11:01:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 08, 2014 11:01:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 08, 2014 11:01:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6144 ms
```

Comment: it gives 404 where ? was the app deployed successfully ?

Comment: yes It was deployed successfully. I got the error when I got i tried to navigate to the page localhost:8080/test-app/LoginServlet1

Comment: Is there some error on tomcat statup?

Comment: what is the name of context path? In tomcat it is represented by war name. It should be `test-app`.

Comment: @Dennis I got that warning during setup can that be part of the problem?

Comment: You should close the `out` but probably not the source problem.

Comment: @user3720999 Can you show your web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Well everything seems fine here. Try deleting the server and creating a new one... and run the project. Tomcat does behave weird sometimes.

Comment: I assume you are running your server within Eclipse right? So when I say delete the server,I mean delete the Server instance.

Comment: Ok now that everything seems fine you've gotta try crazy stuff.
First Try this,
Put href="/LoginServlet" instead of href="LoginServlet".
Second, add a web.xml, yes I know you are following Servlet 3.0 spec so there is no need of web.xml but still add a servlet mapping and see what happens. Please try this don't ignore it, trust me stuff  like this has worked for me before.

Comment: Well Thanks for the replies. I reinstalled eclipse and tomcat and it worked.